# Listener SVG element for key event in D3

Tags: d3.js

I want to find a way to listen other thing that window or body element for keyboard. Basically I have :

```
       // Listen for mouse and keyboard events on the whole document
        this.svg.on('mousedown', function(d,i){ that.mousedown(this, d, i);})
            .on('mousemove', function(d,i){ that.mousemove(this, d, i);})
            .on('mouseup', function(d,i){ that.mouseup(this, d, i);});
        d3.select(window)
            .on('keydown', function(d,i){ that.keydown(this, d, i);})
            .on('keyup', function(d,i){ that.keyup(this, d, i);});
```

But because my whole thing is use into a widget, if I select the window for keyboard action, there will be some conflicts between if there is several widgets. 
So I would like to focus the key event into my svg element (as mouse actions are bind with the SVG). Or maybe if someone has a other idea.

Thank you

Comment: You could attach all listeners to a top-level element and in the handler delegate to the lower-level elements as appropriate (or even call the appropriate handler functions directly).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, is it not already what I trying to do ? 
The problem is not on my mouse event, but the fact is I only can attach to 'body' or window, the listeners for keyboard function I already try to select some other top-level element but it's not working, or maybe I missed something

Comment: That's what I'm saying -- if you capture all keyboard events in a central place, you can then for example query the mouse position and decide where to dispatch the key event to based on that.